# RMAN error RMAN-06207,RMAN-06208,RMAN-06210,RMAN-06211,RMAN-06212,RMAN-06213,RMAN-06214

Tags: oracle, errors, rman

I have this issue with around 7 servers, we have an RMAN job that takes backup and  validate the backup ...

here is RMAN settings:

```
RMAN> show all;

RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name A103775 are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 21 DAYS;
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO 'SBT_TAPE';
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE SBT_TAPE TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE SBT_TAPE PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default

CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE SBT_TAPE TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE SBT_TAPE TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE 'SBT_TAPE' PARMS  'ENV=(TDPO_OPTFILE=C:\RMAN\tdpo_A103775.opt)';
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128'; # default
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'BASIC' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE ; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE; # default
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO 'C:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SNCFA103775.ORA'; # default
```

here is the backup job:

```
connect target backupuser/backuppassword
connect catalog rman/rmanpassword@rcat
run
{
allocate channel tdpo type 'SBT_TAPE' parms 'ENV=(TDPO_OPTFILE=C:\RMAN\tdpo_ADATABASE.opt)';
backup database plus archivelog delete all input TAG 'Full Database Backup';
delete noprompt obsolete;
restore database validate;
release channel tdpo;
}
```

and I get this error message!

```
RMAN-06207: WARNING: 2 objects could not be deleted for SBT_TAPE channel(s) due
RMAN-06208:          to mismatched status.  Use CROSSCHECK command to fix status
RMAN-06210: List of Mismatched objects
RMAN-06211: ==========================
RMAN-06212:   Object Type   Filename/Handle
RMAN-06213: --------------- ---------------------------------------------------
RMAN-06214: Backup Piece    papcfat0_1_1
RMAN-06214: Backup Piece    c-317588623-20140703-03
```

I tried crosscheck and delete obsolete, delete expired ... and it did not help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `crosscheck copy` before deleting:

```
RMAN>crosscheck copy
RMAN>delete noprompt obsolete;
```

Crosscheck on it's own (without copy) doesn't do anything.  You could also have done:

```
crosscheck backuppiece papcfat0_1_1
```